# How to get createdAt property when saving a new object using Parse SDK?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am creating a new object and for some reason I need to get the the full saved object including the createdAt and updatedAt properties.

in this code, I am saving the new object.

```swift
        let msg = PFObject(className: "ChatMessage")
        msg["User"] = user
        msg["Message"] = message
        msg["Topic"] = topic
        //messageList.append(message)
        msg.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //msg.createdAt is nil
            }
        }
```

How can I get the full saved object without making another query to fetch it?

## Edit

this is the vars values

I can see that the "createdAt" value is available inside "_pfinternal_state" object but not in "_estimatedData.

[image]

Is there any way I can access _pfinternal_state._createdAt ?

Thanks

Comment: Your `msg` object should already have these properties automatically set inside/after your callback.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo it has all properties except createdAt and updatedAt.

Comment: Can you double check if the success var is true?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo thanks for the reply, I updated the question. The success value is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a lot of time finding a solution for this small problem.

You can simply. get createdAt and updatedAt values by calling "value(forKey:..." function and cast the returned value to NSDate, as the next code:

```
        let msg = PFObject(className: "ChatMessage")
        msg["User"] = user
        msg["Message"] = message
        msg["Topic"] = topic
        //messageList.append(message)
        msg.saveInBackground { (success, error) in
            if error == nil {
                //msg.createdAt is nil
                let createdAt = msg.value(forKey: "createdAt") as! NSDate 
                // this will return the NSDate object. 
                //   You must cast it to NSDate not Date

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing but it should have an easier way. It is probably a bug in the SDK. Would you mind to open an issue in the [Parse iOS SDK repository](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX)?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo absolutely. Thanks